Hibernate Error: CommandAcceptanceException despite successful SQL Execution in H2 Database
I am working on a Spring Boot application using an h2 in-memory database. I have created a 'Book' entity and corresponding table.
However, I am encountering 'CommandAcceptanceException' error when executing SQL commands, despite seeing that the data is indeed inserted into the database (I check this from the intellij IDE).
Book.java
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

import java.time.LocalDate;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String isbn;
    private String published; 
    private int pages;
}


import.sql:
INSERT INTO Book (title, author, isbn, published, pages) VALUES
('Da Vinci Code', 'Dan Brown', '0001', '2000-01-01', 345);

data.sql
CREATE TABLE Book (
  id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  author VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  isbn VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  published VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  pages INT NOT NULL
);

Here you can see that the book was indeed inserted:
Book table with 1 affected row
This is the error:
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "INSERT INTO Book (title, author, isbn, published, pages) VALUES ('Da Vinci Code', 'Dan Brown', '0001', '2000-01-01', 345)" via JDBC [NULL not allowed for column "ID";]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.applySqlString(Helper.java:233) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.applyScript(Helper.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applyImportFiles(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:676) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applyImportSources(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:595) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:250) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1429) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:322) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1506) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:954) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at com.example.bookapp.BookappApplication.main(BookappApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO Book (title, author, isbn, published, pages) VALUES ('Da Vinci Code', 'Dan Brown', '0001', '2000-01-01', 345) [23502-224]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:520) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:489) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:365) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.table.Table.convertInsertRow(Table.java:936) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:167) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:135) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.command.dml.DataChangeStatement.update(DataChangeStatement.java:74) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:169) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:256) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:262) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:231) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    ... 38 common frames omitted

Thanks for your time!

Have you tried setting @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) instead of AUTO on the id field?

I just did and it displays the same error.

I managed to replicate your error, and I think that the application behavior is a sum of misconfigurations that can be solved easily. More specifically, I solved them using this approach:
The id field is annotated with @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY). If AUTO is used, an error may occurr that Hibernate does not find a BOOK_SEQ sequence.
I changed the names of .sql scripts, using schema.sql for the one that contains the CREATE TABLE statement (i.e. yours data.sql), and data.sql for the one that populates the schema with INSERT (i.e. yours import.sql). Unless customized in the application properties, database initialization scripts have a precise name (cfr. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/how-to/data-initialization.html):

By default, it loads schema scripts from
optional:classpath*:schema.sql and data scripts from
optional:classpath*:data.sql. The locations of these schema and data
scripts can be customized using spring.sql.init.schema-locations and
spring.sql.init.data-locations respectively. The optional: prefix
means that the application will start even when the files do not
exist. To have the application fail to start when the files are
absent, remove the optional: prefix.

I add in the application.yaml the following lines:
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: "none"

Telling Spring that the Hibernate table auto creation has not to be done during startup, and use the init scripts instead.
